# Account TO Contact After Update

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I tried Account To contact trigger in which i wrote a code to change phone of contact as per account Phone Let me know if its comes in best practice. if not so how to do it with best practice..

```
trigger AccountToContact on Account (after update) {
    List <contact> ConList = new List <contact>();

    for(account ac :trigger.new){
        for(contact con :[select id, department, phone, Email from contact where Accountid = :ac.Id]){
            con.phone = ac.phone ;
            
            Conlist.add(con);
        }
    }

    update conList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has the common problem of "SOQL in Loop." You must aggregate all your data first, then do any queries, and finally do any updates. I call this the [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).

Your code does not need to run after insert, as it is impossible for any contacts to exist for the Account at this point.

Here's an update that is probably closer to what you want:

```
trigger AccountToContact on Account (after update) {
    // Query Contacts for these accounts
    Contact[] contactRecords = [SELECT AccountId, Title, Phone FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.new FOR UPDATE];
    Contact[] updatedContactRecords = new Contact[0];
    for(Contact contactRecord: contactRecords) {
        Account accountRecord = Trigger.newMap.get(contactRecord.AccountId);
        // Only update records that require an update
        if(contactRecord.Title != accountRecord.Industry || contactRecord.Phone != accountRecord.Phone) {
            contactRecord.Title = accountRecord.Industry;
            contactRecord.Phone = accountRecord.Phone;
            updatedContactRecords.add(contactRecord);
        }
    }
    update updatedContactRecords;
}
```

Note that this may still cause some problems, so you'll want to think closely about how you actually want this code to work. For example, should it update Contact records if the Account Phone number hasn't changed?

Comment: thank you .....